# javascript typeahead: get selected value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typeahead

I am trying to implement typeahead in in Angular2 app using typeahead.js.

```
<input id="city" type="text" placeholder="Choose City" />
```

**typeahead.d.ts**

```
declare function initTypeahead(data:any,id:any);
export = initTypeahead;
```

**typeahead.js**

```
if ('undefined' !== typeof module) {

module.exports = function initTypeahead(data, element) {

    var _values = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        local: data
    });

    _values.initialize();

    var elt = $(element);


    elt.typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1,

    }, {
            // itemValue: 'code',
            // itemText: 'value',
            name: '_values',
            displayKey: 'value',
            source: _values.ttAdapter(),

        }
    );

    elt.on('typeahead:selected', function (e, datum) {
        console.log(datum.code);
        elt.val(datum.code);
        console.log(elt.val())
    });

}
```

}

Then in the **component.ts**, typeahead function is called as below,

```
initTypeahead(data, '#city');
```

**sample data**

```
[{code: "AUH", value: "Abu Dhabi"}, {code: "ADL", value: "Adelaide"},…]
```

Typeahead is working perfectly. I tried to get selected value of the input filed (city) on a button click as below in my **component.ts** file.

```
$('#city').val();
```

If i select **Abu Dhabi**, it gives **Abu Dhabi** as the selected value of the input field but I need to get the code (**AUH**) as the selected value.

How can I do that ? Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Can you use another hidden field to save code on select?

Comment: @User3250, Is it a good practice?

Comment: I think it shouldn't be an issue. As anyway user can see the values in page source even when you set in textbox. Or use `data-` setting `ele.attr('data-code',datum.code)`